# Need SOQL help with subquery

Tags: soql, subquery

I need a query on Accounts and it's related active Instance where an Entitlement of that Account for a specific product is active. 
Instances and Entitlement do not have a relationship on their own.

```
Account -> Instance : Lookup
Account -> Entitlement : Master-Detail

Need Segment_c,  Account_Status__c from Account FROM Entitlement__c where
Product_name__c CONTAINS ‘xyzabc’ and Active__c EQUALS true
```

And from the same Account record need details of active Instance with its name and status.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I tried to break the task and tired to query the first part like this:

Select Account__r.Segment__c, Account__r.Name, Account__r.Account_Status__C, Name, Product_Name__c, Active__c from Entitlement__c where Product_Name__c = 'xyzabc' AND Active__c = true 

I am now unsure how can I reference the Instance field here.

Comment: Looks like I was able to pull this one using nested query :

Select ID, Name, Instance_Type__c, Instance_Active__c, Account__r.name, Account__r.Segment__c, 
from instance__c
where Account__c in (Select Account__c from Entitlement__c where Product_Name__c = 'xyzabc' AND Active__c = true)
and Instance_Active__c ='Yes' and Instance_Type__c = 'Production Environment'